# PHP Return Array from function

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very simple web app that is capturing RFID tag reads and then submits it into the Database.

I have a function that was to pass the information through a filter and remove the duplicates and then return an array of unique tag reads.

The function looks like this

```
$txtarea = $_POST["rfid"];

rfid($txtarea);

function rfid($txtarea){
  $array = explode("\r\n", $txtarea);

  $rfid_array1 = array_unique($array);

  return $rfid_array1; 
}
```

I then use Print_r to check the contents of the array to make sure it works.

When I run the code inside the function I do not get a result returned but when I run the following outside the function

```
$txtarea = $_POST["rfid"];

rfid($txtarea);

$array = explode("\r\n", $txtarea);

$rfid_array1 = array_unique($array);
```

It returns the values correctly ?

I am very new to PHP so I apologize if this question seems a little basic.

Comment: You are not capturing what is returned by the function `rfid` in the first example. Try `$rfid_array1 = rfid($txtarea);`

Comment: Ah I now see why this could never work, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `rfid` returns a value which you could capture in a variable.

```
$rfid_array1 = rfid($txtarea);
```

Note that you could shorten the function a bit:

```
function rfid($txtarea){
    return array_unique(explode("\r\n", $txtarea));
}
```

Demo on https://3v4l.org/DY8Ts

Comment: Thankyou for your help. This is all makes sense now, yes I will use your example and shorten the code. Thanks again